# How does a parent process read a FIFO after the child process finished the writing that FIFO?

Tags: c, linux, named-pipes, fifo, systems-programming

I have a very simple basic program that has two process first one is `parent` and second one is `child`.

Child process should write some stuff to the `FIFO`. After all writing jobs finished(after the child is terminated). 
Then parent process should read all the `FIFO` file and print to the `stdout`.

So I think, I need a `wait(NULL);` for `parent`. So the `parent` will wait until the `child` is terminated. But `child` is also blocked because of the writing and blocked for reading this writes. So both process wait each other and I think,there occur an deadlock.

My program is this:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <sys/wait.h> 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/file.h>

int writeSomeStuffToFifo ();
void printAllFifo ();

char * myfifo = "myfifo";

int main(int argc, char **argv) { 

    int pid=0;
    int childPid=-1;
    int status;
    pid=fork();


    if ((pid = fork()) < 0){
        perror("fork() error");
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        writeSomeStuffToFifo ();
        exit(1);
    }
    else do {
        if ((pid = waitpid(pid, &status, WNOHANG)) == -1)
           perror("wait() error");
        else if (pid == 0) {
            //child running
            printf("child running\n");
        }
        else {
            if (WIFEXITED(status)){
                printf("child is terminated\n");
                printAllFifo();
            }
            else{ 
                printf("child did not exit successfully\n");
            }
        }
    } while (pid == 0);


    return 0;
}


int writeSomeStuffToFifo (){   //child process will run this function
    int fd;
    mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); 

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"foo1\n",strlen("foo1\n"));
    close(fd);

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"foo2\n",strlen("foo2\n"));
    close(fd);

    fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY);
    write(fd,"foo3\n",strlen("foo3\n"));
    close(fd);
}


void printAllFifo (){     //parent process will run this function
    int fd=open(myfifo, O_RDONLY);
    char* readBuffer=(char*)malloc((strlen("foo1\n")+strlen("foo2\n")+strlen("foo3\n"))*sizeof(char));
    read(fd, readBuffer, strlen("foo1\n")+strlen("foo2\n")+strlen("foo3\n"));
    printf("%s\n",readBuffer );
    close(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`mkfifo()` creates a pipe of limited size. You should not wait in the parent process until the child has finished in order to read, you should read constantly in the parent process while checking if the child has terminated already.

You can use `ulimit -p` in order to read the default size of pipes in your linux system. The number is multiplications of 512, so a value of 8 means 4096 bytes.

Using `pipe()` is more suited to the task than `mkfifo()` because you do not actually need a named pipe. this will provide you with 2 fds, one for read and one for write. In the parent code you close the write fd, in the child code you close the read fd, then you can start reading from the pipe in the parent code until it returns a value <= 0. This would mean that the child process has terminated (and the pipe was closed for writing). then you only need to call `waitpid()` from the parent code to collect the terminated child process.

Comment: I still didn't understand how can I solve tihs problem . How can I increase the size of the pipe? Could you explain with codes?

Comment: You do not increase the size. You just read from it before the child terminates.

Comment: First, I have to use `fifo` beacuse , I will use it in my homework. Also, if I read from it before the child terminates, the child can't writes all the contents and parent read incompeted file.

Comment: The parent needs to read in a loop until it detects that the pipe was closed for writing.

Comment: Okay then , how can I control that pipe was closed for writing?

Comment: You want the pipe to get closed for writing, that's how you detect that the child has finished writing to it. Try opening it for reading before forking, and read from it after forking, but before wait/waitpid

Comment: @still I didn't understand, I need to see some codes to understand. You only explain and don't show the codes.

Comment: Please see my edited question ( I add waitpid in main but it is still blocked).

Comment: I don't have anything to add. I've already explained that you need to read in a loop before waitpid.

Comment: See my post, I have already do that but it cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @EasterGamer: As Shloim explains, the parent process should read from the pipe without waiting for the child. In the parent, simply create the pipe, fork the child, and enter a **loop** that reads from the pipe until nothing more can be read. The read operations on the pipe will automatically wait until the child has written data into the pipe. In the child, write to the pipe and then exit. The two processes will be automatically coordinated by the system. The parent must accept partial sequences of data as they come through the pipe; it should not expect all the data at once. So it must loop.

Comment: @Eric Postpischil , how can I read ? Byte by byte or line by line? And how to know that there is nothing more can be read? Also could you please give piece of code for this solution ?

Comment: @EasterGamer: Read any number of bytes you want using the `read` function. When `read` returns 0 or −1, it means no more data is available (0 for end of data, −1 for error). You should try to write your own code, because that is better for learning.